# SKSpriteNode - Different sprites but same function

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Basically I have this code that only works for "bubble1". Do I need to create many functions of the same type if I want to have another bubble, "bubble2"

```
   func addBubbles() {


    let bubble1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bubble_purple")

    //the new one I want to create
    let bubble2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bubble_green")


    bubble1.name = "bubble1"
    bubble1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bubble1.size.width * 0.5, center: CGPointZero)

    bubble2.name = "bubble2"
    bubble2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bubble1.size.width * 0.5, center: CGPointZero)


    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)



    //Physics implementation of the bubbles
    bubble1.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    bubble1.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    bubble1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bubble
    bubble1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Cones
    bubble1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    bubble1.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a bubble class that extends SKSpriteNode

```
class Bubble : SKSpriteNode
{
    convenience init(imageNamed name:String)
    {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:named)
        self.init(texture:texture,color:UIColor.clearColor(),size: texture!.size())
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.width * 0.5, center: CGPointZero)

        //Physics implementation of the bubbles
        self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bubble
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Cones
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    }
}
```

Then just call your bubbles like this:

```
var bubble1 = Bubble(imageNamed:"bubble_purple")
bubble1.name = "bubble1"
var bubble2 = Bubble(imageNamed:"bubble_green")
bubble2.name = "bubble2"
```

Doing it this way will be overwriting the previous convenience method, and does not allow you to easily extend it to even further classes, so instead I recommend creating a new method to initialize your sprites in case you do need to extend features of this init, like so:

```
     init(named:String)
    {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:named)
        super.init(texture:texture,color:UIColor.clearColor(),size: texture!.size())
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.width * 0.5, center: CGPointZero)

        //Physics implementation of the bubbles
        self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bubble
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Cones
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    }
```

and call your bubbles like this:

```
var bubble1 = Bubble(named:"bubble_purple")
bubble1.name = "bubble1"
var bubble2 = Bubble(named:"bubble_green")
bubble2.name = "bubble2"
```

Comment: You can't override `init(imageNamed: String)`, you must use `init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize)` instead.

Comment: yes, I have already mentioned that in my answer,  I did notice a slight flaw,  forgot to add convenience

Comment: I instead changed my answer to reflect what is going on currently with convenience methods,  so this answer is current as of XCode 7.1.1 and Swift 2.1